# Check If I/O causing high load average

Tags: centos6, io

I wants to understand how to measure if I/O is causing load average high and how to calculate optimal and critical I/O value.

Because sometime there is a load spike on my server but other corresponding servers are normal like DB , Cache. So I wants to understand if I/O causing load spike instead of slow response from DB and Cache.

If this is the Avg / Max IO on machine 105/5.54k then should it be alarming or not. Please help me to understand IO data to identify the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mentioning disk i/o, the you should use the utility like `iostat`, for example `iostat -d 1`, which will show you snapshots of vital disk i/o counters every each second. Among others there will be a `%util` column, showing the total time disk was busy for a given interval. This would be the simpliest representation of a disk i/o bandwidth. If you are talking about CPU load average - then there's plenty of tools like `top`, `htop` etc, which will show you information about CPU utilization. The only context where *load average* is appropriate referencing disks, is SNMP, which operates *disk LA*, which is called because of it's calculation mechanics. Basicly, disk i/o and CPU load aren't connected directly. You cane have high disk i/o but totally idling CPU.